# getting unrecognised escape sequence error

Tags: c#, datatable

I wanted to store value in datatable by a database comparing it with value from textbox, but **I am getting unrecognised escape sequence error** near the connection string. I have tried the techniques given link ---> [[CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456686/cs1009-unrecognized-escape-sequence][1]).
But this has not worked because I will be getting exception called **unrecognized path** . Please tell a fix.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;

public partial class searchsale : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\rdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

            conn.Open();
            string scriptname = TextBox1.Text;
            string accnum = TextBox2.Text;
            string sql = @"select scriptname,accnum,Quantity,price from transac where scriptname = @sn, accnum = @an and transactio = 'Sell'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@an", accnum);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", scriptname);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = GetDataTable(sql);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
    private DataTable GetDataTable (string sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: `@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\rdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"`

Comment: +1 to the comment by @KevinKal. It would also be worth considering moving your connection string to your web config file.

Comment: Which one is failing? The one in Button1_Click or the one in GetDataTable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

`"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\rdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"`

To
`@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\rdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"`

Or
`"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\rdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"`

Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) about the escape sequence in C#.
The `@` in front of a string makes it not do any escape characters.

Comment: sir I have tried those things but it do not work.. it will show few more exception...

Answer (score 3):

Use verbatim `@` before the connection string like

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\rdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

Comment: Bhai thank u for the answer but its not working.. its showing an exception called ."InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized."

Comment: @Darkknight, that exception has nothing to do with this connection string. It's probably because some other part in your code is failing. Show your full code.